# Does this hold in general for inverse function?

Tags: inequality

> Let $z=G^{-1}(y)$ be any number such that $G(z)=y$.

Now,

1. does $z>G^{-1}(y)$ imply $G(z)>y$ in general ?
2. does $z<G^{-1}(y)$ imply $G(z)<y$ in general ?

Comment: Is $z = G^{-1}(y)$ or $>G^{-1}(y)$ or $<G^{-1}(y)$?

Comment: Sir, I have written $z = G^{-1}(y)$, so don't understand what do you ask for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if $G(x)$ is an increasing function, decreasing function, or neither.
($\sin(x)$ is neither because it is increasing sometimes, and decreasing sometimes.)
For example, $G(x)=x^3$ is increasing, and your conclusions are true for that function.